# How to resolve? (Facebook API no working properly after generating apk release mode) ANDROID

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

when i was debugging my app on the mobile, the retrieving of facebook id using facebook sdk is working. but when i generated a release mode apk and install it on my device the app stucked in the part that the program retrieves the facebook id of the user. I think that the obtaining of user's facebook id is not successful.

Comment: check data network or wifi connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug key and Release Key dont have the same Hash..
you need to create with the Keytool hash for your Release key and put it in your Facebook App with the Debug Hash..

you can also View the Hash in the Logcat with no Filter and Verbose.